# Live in NY but work in California

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, payroll-taxes

Which state tax applies if your live in NY and work in California on a job  that will be about 3 or 4 month long.  Company is located in ILL.  Will he pay NY taxes in the state he lives in?

Answer (score 1):

You pay taxes in the state where the [work is performed](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/3265766-if-i-live-in-new-york-but-my-company-is-in-california-do-i-pay-for-califnornia).

> If you  live in NY, and you perform your services for your company in
>   NY, and you do not perform any work physically in the state of CA, you
>   would not pay CA state income taxes.

You may have to [file taxes](https://www.rapidtax.com/blog/state-income-tax-living-in-one-state-working-in-another/) in NY, but you will get a credit in the amount you paid in California, so it'll zero out.

Therefore if you are working physically in California, then you will pay California income tax.

Comment: Thank you,  He will pay California taxes until job is completed.

Comment: The NY state income tax may or may not net to zero after crediting CA's state income tax.